# Javascript Intellisense in VS2013 (PTVS) How to Enable?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ptvs, javascript-intellisense

Why doesn't intellisense for javascript work in VS2013 Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)?

How do I enable intellisense for *.js files?

[image: Broken Intellisense]

[image: MS VS2013 PTVS Version Info]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Visual Studio Shell (probably installed via PTVS Integrated installer). This is a free version of VS that contains core IDE functionality only - this includes some languages (like HTML), but I think it does not include JavaScript. When combined with PTVS, you get support for Python and Django, but PTVS itself does not add JS support.

In PTVS 2.1 beta, we added support for Visual Studio 2013 Express ([Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40747) and [Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787) editions). I would recommend using that instead of PTVS Integrated at this point, as Express includes JS support and much more. Note that you will need to install [VS Update 2 RC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42307) or later for PTVS to work with Express.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I didn't realize the limitations of the Shell version, and played with the settings for a long time in my attempts to get the js intellisense to work. Express is a great solution, but I discovered that students can get Visual Studio Professional for free! So I guess the exercise wasn't in vain. Thank you for the answer. Cheers.